# Query FailedYou have an error in your SQL syntax; near 'DESC' at line 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried many solutions and none have worked. If I comment out the DESC query the page loads fine but no comments, if I put the query back in I get the error. I can't see what I am doing wrong and stuck on this until I sort it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    <!-- Posted Comments -->

<?php //post comments query
$query = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment_post_id = {$the_post_id} ";
$query .= "AND comment_status = 'Approved' ORDER BY comment_id = DESC ";
//$query .= "ORDER BY comment_id = DESC ";
$select_comment_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if(!$select_comment_query) {

    die('Query Failed' . mysqli_error($connection));

}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_comment_query)) {
$comment_date = $row['comment_date'];
$comment_content = $row['comment_content'];
$comment_author = $row['comment_author'];

?>

<!-- Comment -->
<div class="media">
    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
        <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading"><?php echo $comment_author; ?>
            <small><?php echo $comment_date; ?></small>
        </h4>
        <?php echo $comment_content; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php } ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the `=` is unnecessary.  Perhaps you intend:

```
ORDER BY comment_id DESC
```

This orders the result set by `comment_id` descending.

Or, if you want a particular `comment_id` to appear first:

```
ORDER BY comment_id = ? DESC
```

Where `?` is the value you want first.

Comment: Yes that did it Thank you, Thank you. I need a break from coding I think. That was a very quick response. Just waiting to vote your answer as correct.

Comment: And why would a correct *accepted* answer be downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

Order by takes column name with default value ASC.

If you want to sort Data in descending order then after column name put space and add ASC or desc
For sorting in ascending order

```
Order by column_name ASC
Or
Order by column_name
```

For sorting in descending order

```
Order by column_name DESC
```